# Creating jarFile to use Instrumentation for calculating Memory usage of an object in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, instrumentation

I want to calculate the memory usage of my object with help of instrumentation class. I found the [this page](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/instrumentation.shtml) as a straightforward instruction but I do not know how create a jar file in eclipse with the following setting. Where should I mention these setting during exporting JAR file in eclipse?

```
jar -cmf manifest.txt agent.jar mypackage/MyAgent.class
```

To answer question of @Rodrigo Ribeiro; I try to compile my code through command prompt with command *javac MyAgent.java* but I got the following errors since I always work with eclipse I do not know how solve this problem.How can I address this pages address?

I tried to solve my problems based on these pages [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913119/java-compiling-and-running-multiple-packages-from-the-command-line), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20365885/how-do-i-run-java-program-with-multiple-classes-from-cmd) but I could not.

I assume eclipse have this ability but I cannot find it.

[image]

Comment: Why didn't simply use terminal to create this .jar file using the command `jar -cmf manifest.txt agent.jar mypackage/MyAgent.class`?

Comment: @Rodrigo Ribeiro my system is windows and I never work with command prompt and when I compile my code I got the those errors which I do not know how to solve I add them to my question context.